# Recover from broken pi (no python)

Tags: python

I wanted to reinstall python but totally forgot that raspi uses python so I broke it... I restarted it ´cause nothing was running/it was frozen. I got a login screen which I never got before and couldn´t log in the password was correct but it just was stuck in a loop. I can enter the screen terminal thing with "ctrl-alt-F1-6" I have some programming stuff I wasn´t able to save so is it possible to recover it?

EDIT: I also tried it with a USB flash drive but wasn't able to get the stuff it's one folder in /home/pi named HTML

Answer (score 1):

You can mount the SD Card on a Linux machine (which can be a Pi) and read the data.

Comment: Hmm i dont have any Linux machines but Ehen i try like open it with my phone it shows stuff like .dat files

Comment: You have a Pi. Just install Raspbian on a new SD Card.

Comment: What data to read? I think the OP has to deinstall/install/repair things. He could try to `chroot` intto the installation.

Comment: @Fabian You can also use a Live CD from Debian, Ubuntu or so to boot into a Linux system.

Comment: Im not that familiae with Linux so when i reinstall raspbian again how am I able to recover my data how do i Mount it cause the pi only has one sdcard slot right?

Comment: I've had some success using the *Linux Reader* from DiskInternals to mount Raspbery Pi SD cards on my Windows machine and copy files off. Note that it's intended as a data recovery tool so not ideal for editing the files on the disk but OP only seems to want to rescue some files for a corrupted install.

Answer (score -1):

So I'm not sure how I did it. I'd tried all of the answers but then suddenly found the folder in the USB flash drive without ever moving it there because I never found it somewhere else, I don't know. Programming is magic but thanks for all the help.

Comment: What's about your keyboard? You should use a new one.